# Python searching for two words regex

Tags: python, regex, search, nltk, textblob

I'm trying to find if a sentence contains the phrase "go * to", for example "go over to", "go up to", etc.  I'm using Textblob, and I know I can just use below:

```
search_go_to = set(["go", "to"])
go_to_blob = TextBlob(var)
matches = [str(s) for s in go_to_blob.sentences if search_go_to & set(s.words)]
print(matches)
```

but that would also return sentences like "go over there and bring this to him", which I don't want. Anyone know how I can do something like text.find("go * to")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use:

```
for match in re.finditer(r"go\s+\w+\s+to", text, re.IGNORECASE):
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `generator expressions`

```
>>> search_go_to = set(["go", "to"])
>>> m = ' .*? '.join(x for x in search_go_to)
>>> words = set(["go over to", "go up to", "foo bar"])
>>> matches = [s for s in words if re.search(m, s)]
>>> print(matches)
['go over to', 'go up to']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
text = "something go over to something"

if re.search("go\s+?\S+?\s+?to",text):
    print "found"
else:
    print "not found"
```

Regex:-

```
\s is for any space
\S is for any non space including special characters
+? is for no greedy approach (not required in OP's question)
```

so `re.search("go\s+?\S+?\s+?to",text)` would match `"something go W#$%^^$ to something"` and of course this too `"something go over to something"`

Comment: This answer could do with a little more explanation. Perhaps explain what the regex parts - like the word and non-word character types, the non-greedy question mark etc.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
import re
search_go_to = re.compile("^go.*to$")
go_to_blob = TextBlob(var)
matches = [str(s) for s in go_to_blob.sentences if search_go_to.match(str(s))]
print(matches)
```

Explanation for the regex:

```
^    beginning of line/string
go   literal matching of "go"
.*   zero or more characters of any kind
to   literal matching of "to"
$    end of line/string
```

If you don't want "going to" to match, insert a `\\b` (word boundary) before `to` and after `go`.